# Ogre3D+CEGUI Mouse position icon not cleared from screen

Tags: ogre3d, cegui

In our project we are developing an architecture based on plugins.

Each game is set up as a separate plugin and is responsible for establishing the right environment (*SceneManager, SceneNodes, Entities, Lights, ...Cameras,..*)

In our last game using a charger scenes, each scene is set up as a separate file (format .dotscene) with all resources defined graphics.

Within this videjuego CEGUI configure as GUI and this works flawlessly. But to go out and load another game we found CEGUI strange behavior .

The cursor position is updated fine but the icon above position is not clear screen, this causes it to accumulate on the screen

[Sceenshot 1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kuw0yat7r4s2as/ErrorCEGUI.png

Any idea of the cause and how to fix it?

Very thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

For some internal bugs we were creating additional cameras and CEGUI does not work correctly.
After removed those camera and leave on 1 camera and works!